# Getting Subscription Products from WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am trying to access my site's Subscription Products via REST API. At `wc/v1/subscriptions` I can get the active subscriptions, and at `wc/v3/products` I can get all products *except* subscriptions.

There isn't anything in the WC Subscriptions documentation about subscription products. [This site](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/) implies that I can provide an API for this, **but I am not a PHP programmer**. I do have access to the server and can put code in `functions.php` or wherever it would belong.

Can anyone provide me with the code to achieve this? I ask here because I hope it's relatively simple, like the `get_posts_meta` code I've found on a number of blogs/sources to expose some other API data.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you check here? https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/

Comment: I think, you have a better chance of getting an answer, here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/